# How to force all my async functions to be called with implicit await on NodeJS .mjs?

Tags: node.js, async-await

currently I´m developing on nodejs for a competition as I´m more concerned with programming speed than anything else. And I´m doing a completely synchronous process.
The issue is that I connect to MySQL with mysql2 (auth issues with mysql) which is not supported by sync-mysql so I´m forced to use async/await.
So my code is basically filled by unnecessary async/await and to top it up. From time to time I forget to put an await so I don´t notice inmediatelly what the issue is (unlike with non async code). While debugging of course, the debugger will just pass through the code without stoping after exiting the async function. And other nasty asynchronous programming overhead.
Is there a way to make all function calls in NodeJS to do the await through a command line argument?
Something like --AlwaysAwait. So it doesn´t matter how much asynchronicity is shoved into my dependencies, I can always have simple Synchronous code? (I do love async but not when I´m in a competition, it also killed another pet project of mine because it got unmaintainable for the same kind of debugging issues so really want to get rid of it.)
Here is an example of the code:

```js
import mysqlPromise from "mysql2/promise.js";

let errorFunc = function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
};
let configFile = 'config.json';
let config;
if (fs.existsSync(configFile)) {
    const data = fs.readFileSync(configFile,
        {encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'r'});
    config = JSON.parse(data);
}
//break point in this line
let conn = await mysqlPromise.createConnection(config).catch(errorFunc);
//if I forget the next await when I go out of execute i
let [result, fields] = await conn.execute('select ?+? as sum', [2, 2]).catch(errorFunc);
// if I don´t put await in previous line program will keep going without me noticing.
// plus individual catch overhead instead of simply using try and catch as usual if I even wanted that.
```

Remember, I want as less async implementation code as possible so I can focus on more "functionality" code.
Also a deep tutorial is welcome. I have read so many introductory stuff copied all over the web.

I tried searching online for a configuration (only returned basic async/await usage) and tried nodejs --help|grep -i await (only returned --no-experimental-repl-await)
I was expecting someone to already had this issue and found a way to ditch async/await syntax and promises, like PHP but with the perks of nodejs.

Comment: Nope.  You're out of luck.  I guess the lesson here is:  Program asynchronously from day 1.  The world is moving to async.

Comment: No, there is no way to tell Javascript to automatically `await` any async function call.  It's a bit odd that you say you're doing a completely sync process, yet you are calling mysql which is asynchronous.  Once any code in a function is asynchronous, then the whole function becomes asynchronous.  That's just how it works.

Comment: Yes, by synchronous I mean, I will always do await so even if in the backend it is asynchronous, in reality the program doesn´t get any benefit from that asynchronicity.